# Redux-Saga take function with additional arguments

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to create a set of 'taker' functions : functions passed to the take effect in order to share them and make sagas easier to test.

A taker looks like this:

```
export const takeFn = action => action.type === 'ACTION_TYPE'
```

In the saga:

```
yield take(takeFn)
```

That works fine but I don't know how to pass an extra argument to my taker:

```
export const takeFn = action => action.type === 'ACTION_TYPE' && action.payload.arg === **arg**
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll want to make it a higher order function. You pass in some value that you want to check, and you'll get returned a taker function that will check that. For example:

```
export const makeTaker = arg => action => action.type === 'ACTION_TYPE' && action.payload.arg === arg;

// ...

yield take(makeTaker('hello'))
```

Comment: Yeah, that was my first attempt but I've got the same problem for testing than before: the second function remains anonymous and jest cannot perform an equality on it.